# Why does `std::sample` take `UniformRandomBitGenerator` as &&?

Tags: c++, c++17

`std::uniform_real_distribution::operator()` is:

```
template< class Generator >
result_type operator()( Generator& g );
```

while `std::sample` is:

```
template< class PopulationIterator, class SampleIterator,
          class Distance, class UniformRandomBitGenerator >
SampleIterator sample( PopulationIterator first, PopulationIterator last,
                       SampleIterator out, Distance n, 
                       UniformRandomBitGenerator&& g);
```

I'm only referencing `uniform_real_distribution` here because it's another place in the standard which takes a generator, and `sample` and `std::uniform_real_distribution::operator()` take them in different ways. Just curious about the rationale behind this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `sample` ultimately needs a non-const generator, but it's also very convenient to allow temporary generators to be passed in, which wouldn't be possible if it took the generator by non-const lvalue-reference. The obvious solution: a forwarding reference, and an inevitable compiler error if a const lvalue is supplied.

   On the other hand, I suppose it would not be nearly as usual to pass a temporary generator to a single distribution invocation – indeed, given the expense of constructing/initializing most generators, the vast majority of the time doing so would be a pit of inefficiency. In this light, as with e.g. `std::vector`'s lack of `push_front` and `pop_front`, discouraging this inefficiency by actively making it an anti-pattern is probably the best thing to do.
2. Chronologically, `<random>` predates C++11 significantly (it comes from TR1, and Boost before that), and was not necessarily thoroughly updated to exploit new language features when incorporated into the standard.

Comment: on #1: I wasn't trying to imply any relation between `std::uniform_real_distribution::operator()` and `sample` except they are two places in the standard library which take a generator and they don't do it in the same way. on #2: I don't disagree, so why doesn't `std::uniform_real_distribution::operator()` also take it by &&?

Comment: seems like there is only upside (more flexibility) to having the distributions take generators by && as well

Comment: @David : Answer updated. And agreed; however, changing the distributions takes work, and there's no one clamoring for said changes so the work is not likely seen as worth the effort. C++ is a volunteer effort, after all. ;-]